# EE 1.7.0 and white screen on modules page

Tags: blank-screen

I recently moved my ee installation to another server and everything seems ok except for this issue

If i go on modules page i see white screen

Can somebody help me please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Solved: was a fieldframe path issue

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution! It saved me time from poking around.